# How to process list in batches of N elements, without missing the last ones?

Tags: python

Sorry for wording of the question.

I am reading a file and after some operation I am adding that line to a list. I want to read 100 lines, append it to list then send it and repeat the process.

I've been doing `line_count % 100 == 0` then send my list however final 34 lines of code will not get sent, how can I achieve this?

Minimal code to reproduce:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]

line_count = 0

final_lst = []
for line in lst:
    line_count += 1
    final_lst.append(line)
    if line_count % 2 == 0:
        print(f"succesfully sent:{final_lst}")
```

output:

```
succesfully sent:[1, 2]
succesfully sent:[1, 2, 3, 4]
succesfully sent:[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
succesfully sent:[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
succesfully sent:[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

if you print, it will succesfully send up to [1,2,3,....,10]

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: Just show us your code, then we can help you easily.

Comment: Please read [ask]. I have _no idea_ what you're trying to ask.

Comment: reason I didn't post my code is because it contains a lot of info that is irrelevant, I've added a minimal reproducible code. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @lmbloo Here nobody has asked you to provide the code of your project, I have only been asked to provide an MRE that are different things but in the case that your project is small both can be the same. On the other hand, since the MRE does not reflect what you indicate in the description of your problem, then you must explain that part of the output is incorrect and which is the desired output.

Comment: What are you using to send, does it have builtin batching?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more context for this? Depending on what your program is doing there should be a few different solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks)

Comment: Another one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/434287/11301900

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could you simply add a check to do the "sending" always also on the final iteration of the loop:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]

line_count = 0

final_lst = []
for line in lst:
    line_count += 1
    final_lst.append(line)
    if line_count % 2 == 0 or line_count == len(lst):
        print(f"succesfully sent:{final_lst}")
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> succesfully sent:[1, 2]
> succesfully sent:[1, 2, 3, 4]
> succesfully sent:[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
> succesfully sent:[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
> succesfully sent:[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
> succesfully sent:[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
> ```

We can also simplify the code a bit if we use `enumerate`:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]

final_lst = []
for line_count, line in enumerate(lst, start=1):
    final_lst.append(line)
    if line_count % 2 == 0 or line_count == len(lst):
        print(f"succesfully sent:{final_lst}")
```

Comment: This is exactly what @sammy said lol, but thanks

Comment: This will print the same list twice if the number of elements is a multiple of 2. Not sure if this a problem for the OP though.

Comment: @Selcuk Nice point, added a safeguard for that!

Comment: @ruohola You could've changed it to `or line_count == len(lst)` and gotten rid of the final `print`.

Comment: @Selcuk Nice point again :D

Comment: adding another condition `line_count == len(lst)` seems much more cleaner. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could provide an answer where @Selcuk could help :)

Answer (score 1):

You should probably perform an additional final "sending operation" after leaving the code block of the `for` loop.